# how to Align new columns with old columns in Excel

Tags: excel, ms-access

i have an excel file that has been connected to microsoft Access query. after entering data in Ms Access database i can refresh my excel file 
and see which records has been added.

now i want to add some new column to this excel (insert column with Excel) file and entering data in these columns but my problem is new columns i have added are not match with old columns refreshed from ms access query. 
i want also after refreshing new columns still matched with old columns.

before refreshing excel file, my data is like below, column A,B are connected to Ms Access query and column C has been with my self in Excel file:

```
   column A       Column B    Column C

    Doc            Trans       added column in Excel
    doc-100        t-100       r-100
    doc-300        t-300       r-300
    doc-500        t-500       r-500
```

now i add record in ms access database

```
 doc-200    t-200
```

and refresh Excel file, now my data is like below:

```
     column A     Column B    Column C

       Doc           Trans     added column in Excel
      doc-100        t-100      r-100
      doc-200        t-200      r-300
      doc-300        t-300  
      doc-500        t-500      r-500
```

now after refreshing (r-300) is in front of doc-200 , t-200
while should be in front of doc-300, t-300

i want my data after refreshing was like below:

```
      column A     Column B    Column C

        Doc          Trans     added column in Excel
     doc-100         t-100      r-100
     doc-200         t-200      
     doc-300         t-300      r-300
     doc-500         t-500      r-500
```

Comment: Is your 'added column' entered manually, or does it always follow the pattern of "r-"&n, where n is the number element of column 'doc' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a query to external data is refreshed in Excel, several things can happen:

- the query returns the same number of rows
- the query returns more rows than before
- the query returns fewer rows than before

When you use the worksheet grid to enter values against rows returned from the query you need to understand that the query refresh may result in **different** data landing in the same row. What used to be in row 4 may be in row 7 after a refresh. So, if you manually add columns and type in data, a query refresh will wreak havoc with that.

If you want to manually add data to a query, I suggest this approach:

- query the external data and bring it into the spreadsheet
- create a new data table on a separate sheet, where you use the query record's unique key or ID as the first column, and then add data manually into the next columns
- in the query result sheet, add a column where you use a lookup formula to fetch the manually entered data based on the row's ID

Most query types will support additional columns with formulas. If the actual data lives in a different sheet, the formulas will pull the correct data for the row, even if the query returns fewer or more rows after a refresh.

This is a prime example for using Power Query to combine different data sources into one result table. One query to an Access db, another query to a table on a sheet, merge the two into one data result table.

If you have any questions about this, please pipe up.

Comment: thanks, what i understand according your answer, for example i have to add another column (D) for entering lookup formula, now it seems a bit confusing for the user enters data, he/she enters data in column (C) but correct location of data after refresh can see in column (D), what i understand is correct?

Comment: I tried do the my sample in action according to your answer , but I could not do it, if it is possible send a small sample to me, for solving my problem. my email is: masoud_sedighy@yahoo.com

Comment: What aspect could you not get to work? Please be specific.

Comment: thank you, finally i understand what you mean, everything work according to your answer, just i have problem with result of vlookup function when it returns (#N/A) , i like it returns empty cell not "" or #N/A, i like it returns some thing like null in MS Access